# Using scribd in android

Tags: android, scribd

How can I view my Doc file using Scribd in Android.Basically I want to use Scribd Api in my Android code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Crocodoc is the good option to open the documents.After creating
>   session for each document we can view doc with WebView.